# How to automatically repeat a http post request I composed in fiddler once every 5 minutes?

Tags: http, post, request, fiddler

There does not seem to be an option there, I can only execute once.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can replay a transaction x number of times but there is no feature in Fiddler i'm aware of that can schedule it.

you can use any tool that is used to perform load testing e.g. my favorite is Jmeter. jmeter is open source and you can create a test thread with configuration to run it for specific duration and total constant throughput you want in specific duration e.g. 5 minutes in your case.

check below answering the same:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33706/sending-one-http-request-every-30-seconds